# asp mvc razor fill Html.DropDownList

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

In the  controller i have :

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.dData = db.Bank.Select(b => b.Omschrijving).ToList();
            return View();
        }
```

and in the view:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Omschrijving",ViewBag.dData as List<SelectListItem>)

I get a error: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'Omschrijving'
```

How can i fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.dData = db.Bank
        .Select(b => new SelectListItem() { Key = b.Omschrijving }).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

You'll also need to set the `Value` property of the `SelectListItem`.